# converting list of header and row lists into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datanitro

I am reading contents of a spreadsheet into pandas.   DataNitro has a method that returns a rectangular selection of cells as a list of lists.   So

```
table = Cell("A1").table
```

gives

```
table = [['Heading1', 'Heading2'], [1 , 2], [3, 4]]

headers = table.pop(0) # gives the headers as list and leaves data
```

I am busy writing code to translate this, but my guess is that it is such a simple use that there must be method to do this.    Cant seem to find it in documentation.   Any pointers to the method that would simplify this?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Call the `pd.DataFrame` constructor directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=headers)
df

   Heading1  Heading2
0         1         2
1         3         4
```

Comment: 2 by 2 is unfortunate example. I was expecting individual lists to become columns,  but pandas goes across lists and creates columns

Answer (score 111):

With approach explained by EdChum above, the values in the list are shown as rows. To show the values of lists as columns in DataFrame instead, simply use transpose() as following:

```
table = [[1 , 2], [3, 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ['Heading1', 'Heading2']
```

The output then is:

```
      Heading1  Heading2
0         1        3
1         2        4
```

Comment: Are you sure about `df = df.transpose()` ?
I have a list of lists (inner list has 11 elements) and need them in a pandas dataframe the same way, but to get the output you are displaying, I leave out the `transpose`.

Answer (score 10):

Even without `pop` the list we can do with `set_index`

```
pd.DataFrame(table).T.set_index(0).T
Out[11]: 
0 Heading1 Heading2
1        1        2
2        3        4
```

Update `from_records`

```
table = [['Heading1', 'Heading2'], [1 , 2], [3, 4]]

pd.DataFrame.from_records(table[1:],columns=table[0])
Out[58]: 
   Heading1  Heading2
0         1         2
1         3         4
```

Answer (score 4):

From the `table` example, call `DataFrame` constructor as follow:

```py
table = [['Heading1', 'Heading2'], [1 , 2], [3, 4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table[1:], columns=table[0])
```