# Convert List of List into Dataframes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I got some help 2 days ago regarding an issue I was having counting the frequency of 1's, 2's, and 3's in a number of 'hats'.

```
data = {'hat9': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3]], 'hat8': [[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]], 'hat1': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat20': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2]], 'hat3': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], 'hat2': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], 'hat5': [[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1]], 'hat4': [[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]], 'hat7': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], 'hat6': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], 'hat11': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], 'hat10': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], 'hat13': [[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2]], 'hat12': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]], 'hat15': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3]], 'hat14': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]], 'hat17': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]], 'hat16': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3]], 'hat19': [[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]], 'hat18': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], 'hat21': [[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]}
```

Someone provided the following code that iterates through the keys and the list of values, and counts the frequency of 1's, 2's and 3's. To make my life easier when plotting this data, I wanted to put it in a dataframe so, following the example I found in this post, "[Getting List of List to Pandas Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112398/getting-list-of-lists-into-pandas-dataframe)" I used the following code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

keys=[]
values=[]

for key, value in data.iteritems():
    keys.append(key)
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    for x in value[0]:
        if x == 1:
            one+=1
        elif x == 2:
            two+=1
        elif x == 3:
            three+=1
    values.append([one,two,three])

print keys
print values
```

Ideally, my dataframe would have `'hat1'` through `'hat21'` as columns (in the proper order), and in the rows it would consist of the counts of 1's, 2's, and 3's for that respective 'hat'. For example (disregard the numbers), if there were only three hats, below is what I would imagine.

```
      'hat1'    'hat2'    'hat3'
1       27        10        56
2       4         6         254
3       1         1          1
```

When I use the code `df = DataFrame(values)`, however, the dataframe appears to be transposed and I don't quite know how to get the appropriate headers because when I try and use the keys as my headers, I get an error saying `AssertionError: 21 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns`

```
      0    1    2
0    27   10   56
1     4    6  254
2     1    1    1
3     3  480    1
4   252    1    1
5     6   17   10
6     3    2  142
7     6  211    3
8   313    5   12
9     1  193    5
10  243   20   22
11   58   31   93
12    5  190   65
13   80   81  120
14  122   54   18
15  156  154   17
16   76   76   88
17   10   55    8
18  280   26   62
19   19   42   21
20   54   82  310
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **transpose** and **count** to easily achieve what you want, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# use .transpose or .T can transpose your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
# then I simply use list comprehension and count element 1,2,3 in it
# and assign to new column, that's it
df[1] = [d.count(1) for d in df[0]]
df[2] = [d.count(2) for d in df[0]]
df[3] = [d.count(3) for d in df[0]]
```

Results:

```
df.head(10)

                                                       0    1    2    3
hat1                                           [1, 2, 3]    1    1    1
hat10  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, ...  243   20   22
hat11  [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...    1  193    5
hat12  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, ...    5  190   65
hat13  [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, ...   58   31   93
hat14  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, ...  122   54   18
hat15  [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, ...   80   81  120
hat16  [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...   76   76   88
hat17  [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, ...  156  154   17
hat18  [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, ...  280   26   62
```

Finally transpose back and assign data frame with replaced columns:

```
df = df[[1,2,3]].T

print df
   hat1  hat10  hat11  hat12  hat13  hat14  hat15  hat16  hat17  hat18  ...   1     1    243      1      5     58    122     80     76    156    280  ...    
2     1     20    193    190     31     54     81     76    154     26  ...    
3     1     22      5     65     93     18    120     88     17     62  ...    

   hat2  hat20  hat21  hat3  hat4  hat5  hat6  hat7  hat8  hat9  
1   252     10     54     3     3     6   313     6     4    27  
2     1     55     82   480     2    17     5   211     6    10  
3     1      8    310     1   142    10    12     3   254    56
```