# Python convert list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of n items. Each item has 3 columns.

I would like to populate a panda dataframe from my list.

I know I can populate dataframe from CSV file using `pd.read_csv`. But I was wondering if there is something similar for lists like `from_list`

Thanks

Comment: sorry are you after this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112398/getting-list-of-lists-into-pandas-dataframe?

Comment: Yes I think so... I dont know why it didnt work the first time I tried it. Thanks mate. much appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried `df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)`?

Comment: I did... it didn't work the first time. I am embarrassed. Thanks....