# Transform list to dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a list of images and I want to get all the pixels of each image in one DataFrame column and the number of the image into another column. I am trying to do it with

```
plotDF = DataFrame()
plotData = [np.array([[1,2,1],[1,1,2],[4,2,1]]), np.array([[1,2,2,1],[1,3,1,3]]), np.array([[1,1,2,3],[4,1,1,1],[1,1,1,4]])]
plotData = [image.flatten() for image in plotData]
for n, pD in zip(range(len(plotData)), plotData):
    for pixel in pD:
        plotDF = plotDF.append(DataFrame.from_records([{'n': n, 'pixel': pixel}]))
plotDF = plotDF.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but this seems really inefficient.

How can I do this more efficient, possibly with https://github.com/kieferk/dfply?

Comment: Are you after this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112398/getting-list-of-lists-into-pandas-dataframe?

Comment: @EdChum: `plotData` does not come from files. It is the result of image processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for repeat values by legths by [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and flat values of nested `lists` by `chain`.

```
from  itertools import chain

s = pd.Series(plotData)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "n": np.repeat(s.index + 1, s.str.len()),
        "pixel": list(chain.from_iterable(s))})
```

```
print (df2)
    n  pixel
0   1      1
1   1      2
2   1      1
3   1      1
4   1      1
5   1      2
6   1      4
7   1      2
8   1      1
9   2      1
10  2      2
11  2      2
12  2      1
13  2      1
14  2      3
15  2      1
16  2      3
17  3      1
18  3      1
19  3      2
20  3      3
21  3      4
22  3      1
23  3      1
24  3      1
25  3      1
26  3      1
27  3      1
28  3      4
```