# Converting a 2D numpy array to dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list of list that I would like to make it as a row. The closest I got was using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112398/getting-list-of-lists-into-pandas-dataframe). However, I could not get my answer.

For example lets say I have a `testarray` of values,

```
([[ 26.85406494], 
   [ 27.85406494],
   [ 28.85406494],
   [ 29.85406494],
   [ 30.85406494],
   [ 31.85406494],
   [ 32.85406494],
   [ 33.85406494],
   [ 34.85406494],
   [ 35.85406494],
   [ 36.85406494],
   [ 37.85406494],
   [ 38.85406494],
   [ 39.85406494],
   [ 40.85406494],
   [ 41.85406494]])
```

I need like as a `pandas` DataFrame row like this,

```
  Row_value
0 26.85406494
1 27.85406494
2 29.85406494
...
```

I tried the following,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Row_value':testarray})
```

I get an error,

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

How can I pass those values with an index?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use DataFrame constructor only with parameter columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
print (df)
            a
0   26.854065
1   27.854065
2   28.854065
3   29.854065
4   30.854065
5   31.854065
6   32.854065
7   33.854065
8   34.854065
9   35.854065
10  36.854065
11  37.854065
12  38.854065
13  39.854065
14  40.854065
15  41.854065
```

Comment: nice way with column!

Answer (score 4):

Try a `.reshape(-1, )`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Row_value':testarray.reshape(-1, )})
df

    Row_value
0   26.854065
1   27.854065
2   28.854065
3   29.854065
4   30.854065
5   31.854065
6   32.854065
7   33.854065
8   34.854065
9   35.854065
10  36.854065
11  37.854065
12  38.854065
13  39.854065
14  40.854065
15  41.854065
```

It looks like your `testarray` is a 2D array with 1 column. Convert it to a 1D array.

---

The alternative is to not pass a dictionary, but instead pass `testarray` as is, like in jezrael's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I see now, when I have the `reshape`, i don't have to deal with indexing.

Comment: I agree, I like passing the array as is with column :)

Comment: @i.n.n.m Hmm, yeah. It's clean.