# Is there a way to visualise large 2d arrays in python with a scrollable map?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a genetic simulation in python, and I have a map, 'world', which is a 2D list holding all the objects (animals/trees/grass) according to their location. I was wondering if there was a simple way I could use a library such as matplotlib for instance to create a map which you can scroll across, zoom into, and so on from this data. Ideally I would want to have an interface where I could create a dictionary of what to map the characters in the 'world' list to (e.g map 'g' for grass to a green square on the map), and a 2D array of those characters, and produce a map with a simple statement.

If this is not possible I am open to other ideas for visualisation.

EDIT: This is an example of the format my data is in after making it a pandas dataframe (for a 5x5 world map). g is grass, w water, h a herbivore and t a tree

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people in the future, I coded my own map with pygame:

```
import pygame
import random
import os
from math import floor, ceil


screen_width = 1400
screen_height = 700
square_size = 20
pygame.init()


class Map:
    def __init__(self, world, names):
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
        pygame.display.set_caption("Map")

        # creates a dictionary of random colors to represent each character
        colors = {}
        for item in names.keys():
            if item not in colors.keys():
                colors[item] = [random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)]

        # creates a new map with the square sprites in which will form the map
        self.map = []
        self.square_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for i in range(len(world)):
            self.map.append([])
            for j in range(len(world[i])):
                square = Square(colors[str(world[i][j])], i, j)
                self.map[i].append(square)
                self.square_group.add(square)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.square_group.draw(screen)

    def observe(self):
        has_quit = False
        mouse_down = False
        original_x = 0
        original_y = 0
        while not has_quit:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not mouse_down:
                    original_x, original_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    mouse_down = True

                    # quits if the user clicks outside the map (probably a bad way of doing it)
                    if not 0 <= original_x <= screen_width or not 0 <= original_y <= screen_height:
                        has_quit = True
                        pygame.QUIT()

            # scrolls the map around while the user is holding the mouse down
            while mouse_down:
                final_x, final_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                new_x = (final_x - original_x) / square_size + self.x
                new_y = (final_y - original_y) / square_size + self.y
                original_x = final_x
                original_y = final_y
                if new_x > 0:
                    new_x = 0
                elif -new_x * square_size > len(self.map) * square_size - screen_width:
                    new_x = screen_width / square_size - len(self.map)
                if new_y > 0:
                    new_y = 0
                elif -new_y * square_size > len(self.map[0]) * square_size - screen_height:
                    new_y = screen_height / square_size - len(self.map[0])
                for i in range(floor(-max(self.x, new_x)), ceil(-min(self.x, new_x) + screen_width/square_size)):
                    for j in range(floor(-max(self.y, new_y)), ceil(-min(self.y, new_y) + screen_height/square_size)):
                        self.map[i][j].sync(square_size, new_x*square_size, new_y*square_size)
                self.square_group.draw(self.screen)
                pygame.display.flip()
                self.x = new_x
                self.y = new_y

                # checks whether the user has stopped holding their mouse down
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                        mouse_down = False


# class for the squares on the map
class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, colour, x, y, size=square_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.colour = colour
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.Surface([size, size])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, self.colour, [0, 0, size, size])
        self.sync(size, 0, 0)

    # makes sure the square is in the correct position and is the correct size
    def sync(self, size, map_x, map_y):
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x * size + map_x
        self.rect.y = self.y * size + map_y
        pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (size, size))
```

It's not the nicest or the best, but I hope it helps. Feel free to use it as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with pandas and matplotlib.

If you have the longitude and latitude values for each data point, plotting them with a matplotlib scatterplot will give you a map of the data. You can then specify a third column to display some other variable using color or size of scatter dots. In this example I am using population.

Given a csv file that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UOkc.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("./housing.csv")

plt.scatter(data["Longitude"], data["Latitude"], c=data["Population"], cmap="hsv", s=data["Population"]/500)
plt.colorbar()
```

The above code gives you [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5c1T.png) graph

This example is using data only from california, but if you had lat long data from the entire world or area you want to display, you can graph it accordingly.

if you are going to be using a 2d list instead of csv data.  You can turn that list into a pandas dataframe quite easily.  [This question covers how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112398/getting-list-of-lists-into-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Hi there @MattCarlson, I have tried the method pd.Dataframe recommended in the question you linked, but when I tried it on a 100x100 map, it gave me a 100x100 table with the coordinates as the headers, as opposed to a 10000x3 table as you used for your demonstration. Do you know of any neat way to transfer between the two?

Comment: @Arkleseisure could you post a sample of what your data looks like?